# Calling to strings from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

My list (in a txt):

```
a
b
c
d
```

I want to call a function to utilize this list 1 by 1.
Like so: `print (list)` and it does as so:

```
print (list)
a
b
c
d
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Read the file line-by-line and print it? Is that all you need?

Comment: Are there only four lines, or are there n many, that we need to read from the file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to think about the logic of the code carefully. Here, we have defined a function named `search`. Where is the code that will *call* the file? And *what exactly is the question*? Do you know how to get a line from the open file? Do you know how to call the function? If you know both of those things, then what exactly are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Please do not edit questions to replace the title with something meaningless; this is considered vandalism, and will be reverted. There is a deletion feature, but you also should not delete questions to repost them. This sort of behaviour can lead to a [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583). Keep in mind that [there is no sense of urgency](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569) for questions on Stack Overflow - if you feel it isn't getting enough attention, try to improve the question so that people will care about it more.

Comment: Above all else, please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**. See the [tour] and [ask] for details; things work differently here.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a built-in function for reading files: `open`

To read the file, use the following line:

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
```

Next, loop through all of the lines in the file:

```
for line in file.readlines():
```

Finally, print the line:

```
print(line)
```

Giving us the code:

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        print(line)
```

However, this gives us the following output:

```
a

b

c

d
```

This is because, when looping through the lines, python includes the line-break at the end.  To fix this, simply replace `print(line)` with `print(line.replace("\n", "")`.

This gives us the final code of:

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        print(line.replace("\n", ""))
```